# Match and return list in R

Tags: r, match, vlookup

I have data frame with two columns owner and user, both strings, both names. Each row represents a relationship. Owner has posted a question on forum and user has replayed. I need a list of all users when specific user becomes owner. Duplicates are ok, list has to be the same as it is since time variable is present.

```
| Owner | User |   
|-------|------|  
| A     | B    |  
| A     | C    |  
| B     | V    | 
| B     | D    | 
| C     | A    |
```

Output would be a new string column Output for each row and after that categorization of that output. I can do categorization myself.

```
| Owner | User | Output | Cat_output |  
|-------|------|--------|------------|  
| A     | B    | V,D    | indirect   |  
| A     | C    | A      | direct     |  
| B     | V    |        | empty      |  
| B     | D    |        | empty      |  
| C     | A    | B,C    | direct     |
```

I would return this in Excel with [Return MULTIPLE corresponding values for ONE Lookup Value, Horizontally, in one Row](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=119:vlookup-multiple-values-return-multiple-corresponding-values-for-one-lookup-value&catid=77&Itemid=473).

I have to reproduce this in R and can't figure it out.

Thanks
Primoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along similar lines as the others, `split` came to mind...

"Output" as a `list`:

```
df$Output <- with(df, split(User, Owner))[df$User]
df
#   Owner User Output
# 1     A    B   V, D
# 2     A    C      A
# 3     B    V   NULL
# 4     B    D   NULL
# 5     C    A   B, C
```

"Output" as a single character string"

```
df$Output <- sapply(with(df, split(User, Owner)), toString)[df$User]
df
#   Owner User Output
# 1     A    B   V, D
# 2     A    C      A
# 3     B    V   <NA>
# 4     B    D   <NA>
# 5     C    A   B, C
```

Comment: In the end I used this single string solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sapply` and check which are the rows in which a `User` is present in `Owner` column and select the corresponding value.

```
df$Output <- sapply(df$User, function(x) df$User[df$Owner %in% x])

df
#  Owner User Output
#1     A    B   V, D
#2     A    C      A
#3     B    V       
#4     B    D       
#5     C    A   B, C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group_by()` and `summarize()` functions in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(owner = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
             user  = c("B", "C", "V", "D", "A"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE
             )
out <- group_by(df, owner) %>% summarize(output = list(user))
left_join(df, out, by = c("user" = "owner"))

# owner user output
# 1     A    B   V, D
# 2     A    C      A
# 3     B    V   NULL
# 4     B    D   NULL
# 5     C    A   B, C#
```